# View Model Observable Object is not deinitialized during view dismissal

Tags: swift, swiftui, mvvm

I am creating a view model when the fullScreenCover closure is triggered and passing it through PresentedView(). When the modal view is dismissed the view model is never deinitialized? When I toggle the view again, a different instance of the view model is created. Why is swift not deinitializing the observable objects when the view's lifecycle ends?

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var isPresented = false
    
    var body: some View {
        Button("Present!") {
            isPresented.toggle()
        }
        
        .fullScreenCover(isPresented: $isPresented) {
            let vm = ViewModel()
            PresentedView(vm: vm)
        }
    }
}

struct PresentedView: View {
    @Environment(\.dismiss) var dismiss
    @ObservedObject var vm: ViewModel
    
    init(vm: ViewModel) {
        self.vm = vm
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        Text("Presented View").onTapGesture {
            dismiss()
        }
    }
}

class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
    init() {
        print("Init")
    }
    
    deinit {
        print("deinit")
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you check the memory graph to find out what "holds" the view model instance?

Comment: This is SwiftUI where the View struct holds the view data so you shouldn't even be trying to use the legacy view model object pattern. You'll have to learn value semantics, i.e. structs, the View struct and state/binding to use SwiftUI effectively.

Answer (score 1):

First you need to understand that multiple objects of the same view class are instantiated for SwiftUI, for the same view on the phone.  So unlike UIKit, each object of view class actually doesn't hold the observed object instance.   Thus each deinit of each view instance will never call observed object's deinit.  I don't know when will they clear memory for observed object, but you
should not use deinit.  Just use ondisaapear to call observed objects clearing methods